# FindOne got null using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Not sure why this query got me null result. In my collection there's a 'row' which match the given Id.

```
db.getCollection('products').findOne({"_id":"567aa60fbd09dfd4f2f923cc"})
```

Comment: You can try this `db.getCollection('products').findOne({"_id":ObjectId("567aa60fbd09dfd4f2f923cc")})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because object Id is not a string, it is a BSON, you can refer mongodb docs from [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId; 
var o_id = new ObjectID(id);
db.getCollection('products').findOne({"_id": o_id})
```

Comment: weird, in other case I need not to use this and can get some data.